# Processing output from Snowflake Native App into subqueries

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an `employee` table that contains:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID EMPLOYEE_DEPT        EMPLOYEE_NAME
1           Engineering          Tom
2           Customer Support     Joe
3           Finance              Alex
```

The snowflake native app query:

`SELECT app.code_schema.search($url, $table_name, $column_name, $name_to_search);`

this gives me the output:

`['Tomato', 'Tom']`

I want to be able to run a subquery on the output from a snowflake native app like this:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, EMPLOYEE_DEPT FROM employee where EMPLOYEE_NAME IN (SELECT (app.code_schema.search($url, $table_name, $column_name, $name_to_search)));
```

This gives me `Query produced no results` when it should give me the values of employee Tom.

To solve this, I created a temporary table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE employee_arr (
  var variant 
)
AS SELECT PARSE_JSON(SELECT app.code_schema.search($url, $table_name, $column_name, $name_to_search));
```

and tried flattening using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE emp AS
    SELECT
        Y.value:"name"::VARCHAR AS name
   FROM employee_arr, LATERAL FLATTEN(input => var) Y;
```

but this doesn't seem to work since when doing
`SELECT * FROM emp;`

it gives me an empty table

Where I am going wrong and is there a better way of solving this?

Comment: ```JOIN``` operation instead of a subquery. This approach allows you to directly compare values between two tables.

Comment: Hi, what if I must use a subquery rather than a join

Comment: Just make sure that the subquery returns a single value or a set of values that match the data type of the column you're comparing it to. Sample: ```SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, EMPLOYEE_DEPT FROM employee WHERE EMPLOYEE_NAME IN (SELECT value::string FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(input => PARSE_JSON((SELECT app.code_schema.search($url, $table_name, $column_name, $name_to_search))))))```

Comment: This does not work throws an error - `Syntax error: unexpected 'SELECT'.`

Comment: How 'bout change it to ```FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(input => TO_VARIANT(SPLIT(TO_STRING((SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING((SELECT app.code_schema.search($url, $table_name, $column_name, $name_to_search)), ',')), ','))))))``` ?